# Wordpress - Contact Form 7 - Validate Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to validate a custom select field in Contact Form 7.

The custom code [mycode] in the Contact Form 7 is generating the following HTML:

```
<select name="shuttleprice-1" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required shuttleprice" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="0">please choose</option>
    <option value="1">for 1 Person</option>
    <option value="2">for 2 Persons</option>
</select>
```

The official documentation has a post about custom validation: https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/

I took this an build it in my function.php

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_select', 'custom_shuttleprice_validation_filter', 20, 2 );
function custom_shuttleprice_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    if ( $tag->name == 'shuttleprice-1' ) {
        if( $_POST['shuttleprice-1'] == 0 ) {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "Fix input" );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

There are no errors but i still can send the form without changing the select.

Is there something i am doing wrong?
Is the "wpcf7_validate_select" the Problem?

EDIT:
Here the code of the [mycode] (called [shuttleprice] in my code) function:

```
// For the custom Price for shuttle transport
function shuttleprice($atts) {

    $formname = $atts["name"];      
    $max_personen = get_field("maximale_anzahl", $id_a);
    $max_personen_gesamt = get_field("anzahl_maximale_personen_im_shuttle_mit_aufpreis", $id_a);
    $aufpreis = get_field("aufpreis_pro_person_im_shuttle", $id_a);

    $inkl = "";
    $more = "";

    for ($x = 1; $x <= $max_personen; $x++) {
        if($x == 1) {
            $inkl = $inkl."<option value='".$x."'>für ".$x." Person (inklusive)</option>";
        } else {
            $inkl = $inkl."<option value='".$x."'>für ".$x." Personen (inklusive)</option>";
        }
    }

    if($max_personen_gesamt != "") {
        $lauf = 1;
        for ($x = $max_personen + 1; $x <= $max_personen_gesamt; $x++) {
            $more = $more.'<option data-price="'.$aufpreis*$lauf.'" value="'.$x.'">für '.$x.' Personen ('.$aufpreis*$lauf.' € Aufpreis)</option>';
            $lauf++;
        }
    }

    $html = '<select name="'.$formname.'" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required shuttleprice" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                <option value="0">bitte wählen</option>'.$inkl.$more.'</select>';

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('shuttleprice', 'shuttleprice');
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'shuttle1_wpcf7_form_elements' );

function shuttle1_wpcf7_form_elements( $form ) {
    $form = do_shortcode( $form );
    return $form;
}
```

It does nothing fancy just building a select based on conditions.

Comment: Try `if( empty($_POST['shuttleprice-1']) ) {` ?

Comment: try to hook on `wpcf7_validate_mycode`.

Comment: Sorry, but both comments are not changing anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] New answer; **tested and works**.

Replace this:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_select', 'custom_shuttleprice_validation_filter', 20, 2 );
function custom_shuttleprice_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    if ( $tag->name == 'shuttleprice-1' ) {
        if( $_POST['shuttleprice-1'] == 0 ) {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "Fix input" );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

.. and also this:

```
// For the custom Price for shuttle transport
function shuttleprice($atts) {

    // To make this message shorter, I removed the code that was here.
}
add_shortcode('shuttleprice', 'shuttleprice');
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'shuttle1_wpcf7_form_elements' );

function shuttle1_wpcf7_form_elements( $form ) {
    $form = do_shortcode( $form );
    return $form;
}
```

.. with this one:

```
// For the custom Price for shuttle transport
/**
 * Generates a HTML string of two or more `option` elements/tags.
 *
 * @see wpcf7_select_shuttleprice_form_tag_handler()
 *
 * @return string $html
 */
function shuttleprice() {

    $id_a = null;      
    $max_personen = get_field("maximale_anzahl", $id_a);
    $max_personen_gesamt = get_field("anzahl_maximale_personen_im_shuttle_mit_aufpreis", $id_a);
    $aufpreis = get_field("aufpreis_pro_person_im_shuttle", $id_a);

    $inkl = "";
    $more = "";

    for ($x = 1; $x <= $max_personen; $x++) {
        if($x == 1) {
            $inkl = $inkl."<option value='".$x."'>für ".$x." Person (inklusive)</option>";
        } else {
            $inkl = $inkl."<option value='".$x."'>für ".$x." Personen (inklusive)</option>";
        }
    }

    if($max_personen_gesamt != "") {
        $lauf = 1;
        for ($x = $max_personen + 1; $x <= $max_personen_gesamt; $x++) {
            $more = $more.'<option data-price="'.$aufpreis*$lauf.'" value="'.$x.'">für '.$x.' Personen ('.$aufpreis*$lauf.' € Aufpreis)</option>';
            $lauf++;
        }
    }

    $html = '<option value="0">bitte wählen</option>'.$inkl.$more;

    return $html;
}


add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_form_tag_select_shuttleprice' );
function wpcf7_add_form_tag_select_shuttleprice() {
    wpcf7_add_form_tag(
        array(
            'select_shuttleprice',
            'select_shuttleprice*',
        ),
        'wpcf7_select_shuttleprice_form_tag_handler',
        array(
            'name-attr'         => true,
            'selectable-values' => true,
        )
    );
}

function wpcf7_select_shuttleprice_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {
    return str_replace( '</select>', shuttleprice() . '</select>', str_replace(
        '<option value="">---</option>', '', wpcf7_select_form_tag_handler( $tag )
    ) );
}


add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_select_shuttleprice', 'wpcf7_select_shuttleprice_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_select_shuttleprice*', 'wpcf7_select_shuttleprice_validation_filter', 10, 2 );
function wpcf7_select_shuttleprice_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    $name = $tag->name;
    $empty = ( empty( $_POST[ $name ] ) || '0' === $_POST[ $name ] );

    if ( $tag->is_required() && $empty ) {
        $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_required' ) );
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And replace the `[mycode]` with:

```
[select_shuttleprice* shuttleprice-1 class:shuttleprice]
```

Comment: The validation filter didn't work because the `select` element was not added by the Contact Form 7 system. I have updated my answer, so please check it out and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The select seems to be registered in the CF7 now and your code is fine, but when i send the form, i get a POST Error 500  
send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4  
ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4  
e.fn.ajaxSubmit @ jquery.form.min.js?v….51.0-2014.06.20:11  
t @ jquery.form.min.js?v….51.0-2014.06.20:11  
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3  
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3

Comment: Which CF7 version are you using? Also, are there any JS/jQuery scripts written specifically for the "shuttleprice" `select`/drop-down menu? Try to disable AJAX submission for a while and see if the form submits properly. [This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-extras/) can help you disable the AJAX submission.

Comment: I am using 4.7 of CF7. The application needs the on_sent_ok function so i can update to 4.9 but i dont think there will be a lot of different.

After disabling AJAX there is a new error:
"Cannot read property 'contactFormId' of undefined" from the control.js of the new plugin.

And the custom field is still not marked as missing.

Comment: So, i just tried some things and now the form is sending. However, right before he is leaving the site in the console is the same POST error as before and then he redirects to an empty page (same URL as the form, but its not loading). There is no error message whatsoever..
I think there might be some issues with the current JS which is already implemented..

Comment: Alright, it seems to me that you're still using some outdated WordPress stuff.. (plugins, themes, templates, etc.) If you go install WordPress in a new directory/domain/subdomain and install the latest CF7 and then install the code I provided, I'm pretty sure that things would work as expected.

Comment: Thats not an option i guess but i still will give you the correct answer since you solved my initial question! Thanks alot sir!

Comment: You're welcome! But actually, I didn't mean to ask you to select my answer as the "best" answer. I was just saying that you should consider upgrading to the latest CF7 release. =) If you're worried because the `on_sent_ok` was removed, then don't worry, I can help you achieve whatever you wanted to do with that deprecated hook.